# Why constexpr std::string_view yields "format not a string literal" warning?

Tags: c++, constexpr, string-literals, string-view

The following use of constexpr std::string_view produces "format not a string literal" warning:

```
constexpr std::string_view string_view_format_str = "hello %s";
snprintf(string_view_warning, 100, string_view_format_str.data(), "world");

warning: format not a string literal, argument types not checked [-Wformat-nonliteral]
```

And doing the following afterwards, doesn't:

```
constexpr const char * const_char_format = string_view_format_str.data();
snprintf(string_view_warning, 100, const_char_format, "world");
```

Why constexpr string_view produces that warning?

https://godbolt.org/z/hT6xqhGeW

Both GCC and clang give the same result:

- GCC (trunk) with -Wformat, -Wformat-nonliteral
- clang (> 5.0.0) with -Weverything

Comment: Note that it's only the `string_view_format_str` object that is a `constexpr`, the string it points to will not necessarily be.

Comment: Note that C++20 now has it's own [formatting library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok, if I do `std::string_view sv = "hello %s"; constexpr const char * str = sv.data()` the compiler will throw error because "sv is not usable in a constexpr context". But if I do `constexpr std::string_view sv = "hello %s"; constexpr const char * str = sv.data()` everything is fine. Therefore, I understand that, in the latter expression, the string it points to is constexpr. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The warning isn't for `string_view`, it's for `snprintf`. That's a C function, and there's no `constexpr` in C, so it makes sense that GCC didn't bother.

Comment: Indeed it's `snprintf`. But why `constexpr const char* foo = "..."` is accepted? Please note that `const char* foo ="..."`, effectively, throws the same warning. Therefore, it doesn't seem a matter of C functions not being constexpr. I'm afraid I cannot understand the rationale behind that warning

Comment: @osovan: Compilers aren't magic. You're mixing two languages, and at the boundary of the two languages you're seeing implementation details shining through. In the next version of GCC, things might be different again. There is no C++ rationale for that warning. There is a C rationale, but C doesn't have `constexpr`.

Answer (score 2):

> Why constexpr `string_view` produces that warning?

I don't know.

[gcc-11](https://godbolt.org/z/n87G69ETd) does not produce such warnings, so this should be a recent enhancement of gcc. As for [clang-trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/j8x8rzveE), it still produces a warning for the second case, which may indicate that it has something to do with the compiler's implementation of diagnostics.

If you need `string_view::data()` to execute at compile-time,  in C++20 you can

```
consteval auto as_constexpr(auto x) { return x; }

constexpr std::string_view string_view_format_str = "hello %s"
snprintf(
  string_view_warning, 100, 
  as_constexpr(string_view_format_str.data()), 
  "world");
```

which will suppress gcc-trunk's warnings.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/54GGfz3cj)

Comment: Interesting. A similar approach for c++17: https://godbolt.org/z/3oYTvxsYf